# Getting counts of overlapping dataframe values without a for loop in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, one called `segments` containing numeric "start" and "stop" values

```
segments <- as.data.frame(
  cbind(
    rep(seq(1, 22, 1), 2),
    seq(500000, 3000000, 57000),
    seq(1000000, 3500000, 57000)
  )
)
colnames(segments) <- c("chr", "segment.start", "segment.end")
```

And another, called `positions` which contains numeric values.

```
positions <- as.data.frame(cbind(1, seq(750000, 2000000, 56000)))
colnames(positions) <- c("chr", "pos")
```

I am interested in counting the number of rows in `segments` where the area between the "start" and "stop" values overlap each of the values in `positions` and adding those counts to a new column of `positions`.

```
positions$count <- 0
```

I can get these counts using the following for loop, but on large datasets this is very slow.

```
for (n in 1:nrow(segments)) {
  segment <- segments[n, ]
  to.update <- which(
    positions$pos >= segment$segment.start &
      positions$pos <= segment$segment.end & 
      positions$chr == segment$chr
    )
  positions[to.update, "count"] <- positions[to.update, "count"] + 1
}
```

Does anyone know how to get these counts without a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without verification, I think this can be done well with `data.table`. I'm sure it can be done with other tools (base or `tidyverse`), but this was fast and uses a tool I've recently been working a lot with: [`foverlaps`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/foverlaps).

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(segments)
setDT(positions)
positions[, pos2 := pos ]

setkey(segments, segment.start, segment.end)
setkey(positions, pos, pos2)
```

As a point of explanation, `foverlaps` requires that both frames have two fields, with the premise of the function being an overlap in the range of one frame with the overlap of the other frame. As much as one might argue that having a single column option in this overlap-check might be useful, the addition of a second column (`pos2` in this case) is trivial and enables exactly the same functionality without changing `data.table` code.

**Edit**: updated to include "by `chr`" logic.

**Edit 2**: inverted, resulting in `positions` as the primary:

```r
foverlaps(positions, segments) [
    , .(count = sum(!is.na(segment.start))), by = .(chr, pos, pos2) ][
    , pos2 := NULL ]
#     chr     pos count
#  1:   1  750000     1
#  2:   1  806000     1
#  3:   1  862000     1
#  4:   1  918000     1
#  5:   1  974000     1
#  6:   1 1030000     0
#  7:   1 1086000     0
#  8:   1 1142000     0
#  9:   1 1198000     0
# 10:   1 1254000     0
# 11:   1 1310000     0
# 12:   1 1366000     0
# 13:   1 1422000     0
# 14:   1 1478000     0
# 15:   1 1534000     0
# 16:   1 1590000     0
# 17:   1 1646000     0
# 18:   1 1702000     0
# 19:   1 1758000     1
# 20:   1 1814000     1
# 21:   1 1870000     1
# 22:   1 1926000     1
# 23:   1 1982000     1
#     chr     pos count
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do this that takes in account the `chr` column present in both dataframes? I only want to record an overlap if the `positions` value is between `segment.start` and `segment.end` AND the `chr` column is the same between the two dataframes.

Comment: I am actually interested in the inverse `foverlaps(positions, segments) [
  , .(n = .N), by = .(pos, pos2) ]` , which does not return the correct values for `n` (n=1 for all values of `pos` when for many of the middle values `n` should be 0 because they do not overlap with a segment where `chr`=1)

Comment: Yup, sorry, I didn't compare with your `for` loop output. How about now?

Comment: This works perfectly on my larger dataset if I make one minor tweak `newdepthcounts<-foverlaps(bim, seg.file) [, .(count = sum(!is.na(segment.start))), by = .(chr,pos, pos2) ][, pos2 := NULL ]`. Thanks!